# Can you reuse an init.mp4 file for two separate FMP4 videos if they are encoded to the same specification?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, fmp4

I have two separate FMP4 (Fragmented MP4) videos that I need to encode. Both videos will be encoded to the same specifications, including resolution, bitrate, and codec settings. I understand that each FMP4 video typically includes an init.mp4 file containing initialization data.

My question is: can I reuse the same init.mp4 file for both videos since they are encoded to the same spec? Would this cause any issues with playback compatibility or any other potential problems?

Since the moov atom contains general info and timing information meta-data, and both videos are encoded to the same specification, my thought is you could reference one init file for playback of both videos. If I could guarantee that encoding specifications are the same, what would be the consequence of such an approach?